# symfony2 assetic css/sass: get Internal Server Error only in dev .css file

Tags: css, symfony, sass, compass-sass, assetic

I'm trying out symfony2 and its assetic with compass/sass. But it is an error in the compiled css file when I am only in dev environment:

```
/*
[exception] 500 | Internal Server Error | Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ContextErrorException
[message] Warning: file_put_contents(): Filename cannot be empty in /Users/kklaus/Workspace/Symfony/vendor/kriswallsmith/assetic/src/Assetic/Filter/CompassFilter.php line 312
[1] Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ContextErrorException: Warning: file_put_contents(): Filename cannot be empty in /Users/kklaus/Workspace/Symfony/vendor/kriswallsmith/assetic/src/Assetic/Filter/CompassFilter.php line 312
    at n/a
        in /Users/kklaus/Workspace/Symfony/vendor/kriswallsmith/assetic/src/Assetic/Filter/CompassFilter.php line 312

    at Symfony\Component\Debug\ErrorHandler-&gt;handle(&#039;2&#039;, &#039;file_put_contents(): Filename cannot be empty&#039;, &#039;/Users/kklaus/Workspace/Symfony/vendor/kriswallsmith/assetic/src/Assetic/Filter/CompassFilter.php&#039;, &#039;312&#039;, array(&#039;asset&#039; =&gt; object(FileAsset), &#039;root&#039; =&gt; &#039;/Users/kklaus/Workspace/Symfony/app/../web&#039;, &#039;path&#039; =&gt; &#039;bundles/webdevblog/sass/style.scss&#039;, &#039;loadPaths&#039; =&gt; array(&#039;/Users/kklaus/Workspace/Symfony/app/../web/bundles/webdevblog/sass&#039;), &#039;tempDir&#039; =&gt; &#039;/private/var/folders/nx/kydlggls2l92jf69_dp_sy5c0000gn/T&#039;, &#039;compassProcessArgs&#039; =&gt; array(&#039;/usr/bin/ruby&#039;, &#039;/usr/bin/compass&#039;, &#039;compile&#039;, &#039;/private/var/folders/nx/kydlggls2l92jf69_dp_sy5c0000gn/T&#039;), &#039;pb&#039; =&gt; object(ProcessBuilder), &#039;optionsConfig&#039; =&gt; array(&#039;additional_import_paths&#039; =&gt; array(&#039;/Users/kklaus/Workspace/Symfony/app/../web/bundles/webdevblog/sass&#039;), &#039;sass_options&#039; =&gt; array(&#039;cache_location&#039; =&gt; &#039;/var/folders/nx/kydlggls2l92jf69_dp_sy5c0000gn/T&#039;), &#039;http_path&#039; =&gt; &#039;/images&#039;), &#039;config&#039; =&gt; array(&#039;additional_import_paths = [
    &amp;quot;/Users/kklaus/Workspace/Symfony/app/../web/bundles/webdevblog/sass&amp;quot;
]&#039;, &#039;sass_options = {
    :cache_location =&amp;gt; &amp;quot;/var/folders/nx/kydlggls2l92jf69_dp_sy5c0000gn/T&amp;quot;
}&#039;, &#039;http_path = &amp;quot;/images&amp;quot;&#039;), &#039;name&#039; =&gt; &#039;http_path&#039;, &#039;value&#039; =&gt; &#039;/images&#039;, &#039;configFile&#039; =&gt; false))
        in  line 

    at file_put_contents(&#039;&#039;, &#039;additional_import_paths = [
    &amp;quot;/Users/kklaus/Workspace/Symfony/app/../web/bundles/webdevblog/sass&amp;quot;
]
sass_options = {
    :cache_location =&amp;gt; &amp;quot;/var/folders/nx/kydlggls2l92jf69_dp_sy5c0000gn/T&amp;quot;
}
http_path = &amp;quot;/images&amp;quot;
&#039;)
        in /Users/kklaus/Workspace/Symfony/vendor/kriswallsmith/assetic/src/Assetic/Filter/CompassFilter.php line 312

    at Assetic\Filter\CompassFilter-&gt;filterLoad(object(FileAsset))
        in /Users/kklaus/Workspace/Symfony/vendor/kriswallsmith/assetic/src/Assetic/Filter/FilterCollection.php line 62

    at Assetic\Filter\FilterCollection-&gt;filterLoad(object(FileAsset))
        in /Users/kklaus/Workspace/Symfony/vendor/kriswallsmith/assetic/src/Assetic/Asset/BaseAsset.php line 90

    at Assetic\Asset\BaseAsset-&gt;doLoad(&#039;
body {
  background-color: yellow;
}


h2 {
  color: green;

}

p {
  span {
    font-weight: bold;
  }
}&#039;, null)
        in /Users/kklaus/Workspace/Symfony/vendor/kriswallsmith/assetic/src/Assetic/Asset/FileAsset.php line 65

    at Assetic\Asset\FileAsset-&gt;load()
        in /Users/kklaus/Workspace/Symfony/vendor/kriswallsmith/assetic/src/Assetic/Asset/BaseAsset.php line 99

    at Assetic\Asset\BaseAsset-&gt;dump(null)
        in /Users/kklaus/Workspace/Symfony/vendor/kriswallsmith/assetic/src/Assetic/Asset/AssetCache.php line 69

    at Assetic\Asset\AssetCache-&gt;dump()
        in /Users/kklaus/Workspace/Symfony/vendor/symfony/assetic-bundle/Symfony/Bundle/AsseticBundle/Controller/AsseticController.php line 88

    at Symfony\Bundle\AsseticBundle\Controller\AsseticController-&gt;render(&#039;56ff856&#039;, &#039;0&#039;)
        in  line 

    at call_user_func_array(array(object(AsseticController), &#039;render&#039;), array(&#039;56ff856&#039;, &#039;0&#039;))
        in /Users/kklaus/Workspace/Symfony/app/bootstrap.php.cache line 2844

    at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel-&gt;handleRaw(object(Request), &#039;1&#039;)
        in /Users/kklaus/Workspace/Symfony/app/bootstrap.php.cache line 2818

    at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel-&gt;handle(object(Request), &#039;1&#039;, true)
        in /Users/kklaus/Workspace/Symfony/app/bootstrap.php.cache line 2947

    at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\DependencyInjection\ContainerAwareHttpKernel-&gt;handle(object(Request), &#039;1&#039;, true)
        in /Users/kklaus/Workspace/Symfony/app/bootstrap.php.cache line 2249

    at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel-&gt;handle(object(Request))
        in /Users/kklaus/Workspace/Symfony/web/app_dev.php line 28


*/
```

When I'm in the prod environment, it works. The CSS file is correct:

```
/* line 2, assetic_compass67JtN2.scss */
body {
  background-color: yellow;
}

/* line 7, assetic_compass67JtN2.scss */
h2 {
  color: green;
}

/* line 13, assetic_compass67JtN2.scss */
p span {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

Asstetic configuration in config.yml:

```
# Assetic Configuration
assetic:
    debug:          %kernel.debug%
    use_controller: false
    bundles:        [ ]
    #java: /usr/bin/java
    ruby: /usr/bin/ruby
    filters:
        cssrewrite: ~
        sass:
          bin: /usr/bin/sass
        compass:
          bin: /usr/bin/compass
```

Do somebody know where is the mistake and why it does not work on dev?

Comment: Dump asset files for dev environment and see if it helps: [directions here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/assetic/asset_management.html#dumping-asset-files-in-the-dev-environment) The downside is that if you change something in asset files you need to dump it again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks [@Djuro Mandinic](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2484968/djuro-mandinic) for solution:

> Dump asset files for dev environment and see if it helps: [directions here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/assetic/asset_management.html#dumping-asset-files-in-the-dev-environment) The downside is that if you change something in asset files you need to dump it again.

Comment: The other downside is that it is difficult to debug javascript when it is dumped (and compressed) in dev environment.